# Scrolling causes an error with React image lightbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightbox, react-image-lightbox

I have a create-react-app project which i am building, all has been going great up until recently.

For some reason, all of a sudden i am getting an error when scrolling after clicking a lightbox object.

The error i am getting is;

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.`

There has been no code updates, nothing changed at all ... It just started happening out of no where and I can't trace whats going on.

My package.json says i am using the following;

`"react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.0"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This also happens on [their official demo](https://frontend-collective.github.io/react-image-lightbox/ )
I think this is because they listen to scroll event to scale the image... maybe use another lightbox gallery?

Comment: Hey @cloned ... Oh wow, it does too ... I should have checked that ... Thanks for the heads up!